# Selecting father element in jQuery with selectors (no traversing)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to select the father element (the `<td>` in this case) of the child (the `<input>`) you can see in the second line of code:

```
<td class="pbButton">
<input value="Add to Campaign" class="btn" name="addCampaign" onclick="javascript: openLookup('/_ui/common/data/LookupPage?lkpr=00Qo000000GyyNl&amp;lktp=701&amp;enableScopes=1&amp;addToCampaign=1',670,'1','')" title="Add to Campaign" type="button"></td>
```

There are two limitations:

1. I have to use jQuery selectors only (no traversing can be used).
2. I don't know anything about the father element (it can be any HTML
   element, any class or id, etc.).

What's the best method of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using .parent() of jquery?

Comment: @NikhilBatra: *"no traversing can be used"*

Comment: Josh, it's **well worth** your time to read through [the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com) beginning to end. It takes an hour or two at most, and repays that time *immediately*.

Comment: Thanks T.J., I would do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the :has() selector

```js
$('*:has( > input[name="addCampaign"])').css('background-color', 'lightgrey')
```

```css
td {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="pbButton">
      <input value="Add to Campaign" class="btn" name="addCampaign" onclick="javascript: openLookup('/_ui/common/data/LookupPage?lkpr=00Qo000000GyyNl&amp;lktp=701&amp;enableScopes=1&amp;addToCampaign=1',670,'1','')" title="Add to Campaign" type="button" />
    </td>
    <td>something else</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why don't you use Stack Snippets, so demos are on-site? Sure, [they have issues](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239706/134069), but still...